# Broadcast Receiver is not starting an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver

In alarm Manager application.
This is My Scheduler Class:

```
class AndroidAlarmScheduler(val context: Context) : AlarmScheduler {
    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun schedule(alarmData: AlarmData) {
        val currentDate = LocalDateTime.now()
        // Combine the current date with the provided time to create a LocalDateTime
        val dateTimeToSchedule = LocalDateTime.of(currentDate.toLocalDate(), alarmData.time)
        // Get the epoch milliseconds from LocalDateTime
        val milliseconds =   dateTimeToSchedule.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()

        val intent = Intent(context,AlarmCancelHandler::class.java)

        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            milliseconds,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarmData.id.toInt(),
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        )
        Log.d("CHECKITOUT","ALARM SET")
    }

    override fun cancel(alarmData: AlarmData) {
        alarmManager.cancel(
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                alarmData.id.toInt(),
                Intent(context, AlarmCancelHandler::class.java),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
              )
          )
       }
}
```

My Broadcast Receiver Code:

```
class AlarmCancelHandler : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("CHECKITOUT", "ON RECEIVE CANCEL")

        val newIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiveActivity::class.java)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

        try {
            context?.startActivity(newIntent)
            Log.e("CHECKITOUT", "Activity started successfully")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("CHECKITOUT", "Error starting activity: $e")
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when app is in background - activity instantly comes to front on specified time, but when I remove the app from background Logcat shows `OnReceive` and Activity Started but Activity is not launched

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot launch activities from the background on modern versions of Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). Please display a `Notification` instead.